# automatic differentiation and getting the next representable floating point value

Tags: c++, c++20, automatic-differentiation

Getting the next representable floating point number of type `T` greater than a given `T x` can be achieved by calling `std::nextafter(x)` or, assuming `T = double`, `next_double_up(x)`, where

```
double next_double_up(double v)
{
    if (std::isinf(v) && v > 0)
        return v;
    if (v == -0)
        v = 0.f;
    std::uint64_t ui = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(v);
    if (v >= 0)
        ++ui;
    else
        --ui;
    return std::bit_cast<double>(ui);
}
```

However, now I need to do this for `T = CppAD::AD<U>`, where `U` is a floating point type. I clearly cannot use `std::nextafer` or my `next_double_up` here. (And even if I could, the operations involved are clearly not differentiable.)

What can I do here? Would it be a good idea to simply add a "nice" positive `epsilon`? If so, how should I choose it? Maybe `epsilon = std::numeric_limits<U>::epsilon()`?

I think I cannot prevent to end up with a larger value than what would really be the "next" greater value. However, it is more important I guess that the obtained value is actually larger.

Comment: I believe we can come up with a differentiation for `std::nextafer`. Why not? Can we plug it into CppAD?

Comment: We can't help without knowing what you need this nextafter value for.

Comment: Why do you need `nextafter` for automatic differentiation to begin with? That sounds like numeric differentiation. Automatic diff. is supposed to use the chain rule and the basic rules for calculating the diff. of elemental mathematical operations.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I'm performing a 3d geometry intersection computation. The intersection point might suffer from rounding errors. I need to correct them. It is similar to what's described here: https://pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Shapes/Managing_Rounding_Error.

Comment: @Homer512 See my comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `CppAD::AD<U>`, where `U` is a floating point type, you're correct that typical bitwise operations won't work and are not differentiable.

Adding a "nice" positive epsilon is a viable workaround. Using `std::numeric_limits<U>::epsilon()` as epsilon could be a reasonable choice.

Here's a simplified code snippet:

```cpp
#include <CppAD/CppAD.hpp>
#include <limits>

template<typename U>
CppAD::AD<U> next_ad_up(CppAD::AD<U> x) {
    CppAD::AD<U> epsilon = CppAD::numeric_limits<CppAD::AD<U>>::epsilon();
    return x + epsilon;
}
```

This method should be differentiable and fulfills your requirement of getting a larger value. However, note that the increment is based on machine epsilon, and might not be the "next representable" value in the same sense as `std::nextafter` or `next_double_up`.

Keep in mind:

- If you're optimizing a function that is sensitive to very small changes, adding epsilon could introduce numerical instability.
- The choice of epsilon could be problem-specific. You might need to tune it based on your specific use case.

Comment: x*(1+eps) may make more sense than x+eps.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Does not work when `x < 0`. Maybe replace by `x * (1 - eps)` in that case?

Comment: You can also use `CppAD::numeric_limits<CppAD::AD<U>>::epsilon`.